# Display certian divs in one php include, and all divs in another

Tags: php, html, css

I have some content stored in php files that I want to include two places on my page.
In the first place I want to include all of the content, but in the second place I just want to include content in certain divs with a given class.

For example I have the following files:

```
index.php
content.php
list.php
problems.php
```

`index.php` have the following content: `<?php include "list.php"; include "problems.php"; ?>`.

Both `list.php`and `problems.php`contains `<php include "content.php"; ?>`

`content.php`have the following content:

```
<div class="up">This location is up</div>
<div class="down">This location is down</div>
```

How can I display all content of `content.php` with `list.php`, and only display content with `div class="down"` in `problems.php`?

I tried to add

```
<style>
.up {display:none}
</style>
```

in `problems.php`, but this removed all `div class="up"` from both includes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the id to distinguish

in problems.php

```
<div id='problems'><php include "content.php"; ?></div>
<style>
   #problems .up {display:none}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).

> The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file
>   during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the
>   include statement, with the only difference being that if the code
>   from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.
>   As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

Comment: Thanks, but the last include of content.php still overrides the first when I try to hide the `div class="up"`...